# Spectral resolution of discrete Laplacian on $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, self-adjoint-operators

Let $\Delta$ be the discrete Laplacian on $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$, that is, $$\Delta = 1- \frac{S+S^*}{2},$$
where $S$ is the right shift operator. I know that $\Delta$ is a bounded self-adjoint operator. Do you know if there is some kind of explicit expression for the spectral resolution of $\Delta$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the unitary mapping
$U:\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})\to L^2(-\pi,\pi)$
$$U\{a_n\}=(2\pi)^{-1/2}\sum_{-\infty}^\infty a_ne^{int}$$
Then $(USU^{-1}f)(t)=e^{it}f(t),$ hence
$$(U\Delta U^{-1}f)(t)=(1-\cos t )f(t),\quad f\in L^2(-\pi,\pi)$$
The operator $U\Delta U^{-1}$ is unitarily equivalent to $\Delta$ and is represented in generalized diagonal form.
The operator $U\Delta U^{-1}$ is unitarily equivalent to the direct sum of  the operator $M$ with itself, where
$M:L^2(0,\pi)\to L^2(0\,\pi)$ and
$$(Mf)(t)=(1-\cos t)f(t)$$
The spectral resolution of $M$ can be easily read off, by substituting $x=1-\cos t.$  Indeed, consider the mapping
$$V:L^2((0,2),\mu)\to L^2(0,\pi)$$ given by
$$(Vf)(t)=f(1-\cos t),\quad d\mu(x)=x^{-1/2}(2-x)^{-1/2}\,dx$$
Then $V$ is unitary and
$$(V^{-1}MV)f(x)=xf(x),\quad f\in L^2((0,2),\mu)$$

Answer (score 0):

$S^*$ is the left shift.  Consider the functions on $\psi_\theta(n) = e^{i n \theta}$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}, \theta\in[0,2\pi)$.  Then
$$S \psi_\theta(n) = e^{i (n-1) \theta} = e^{-i\theta} \psi_\theta(n)$$
and
$$S^* \psi_\theta(n) = e^{i (n+1) \theta} = e^{i\theta} \psi_\theta(n)$$
So the functions $\psi_\theta$ are generalized eigenvectors (yes, I'm aware they're not in $l^2(\mathbb{Z})$) for $S, S^*$ - unitary operators whose spectrum is the entire unit circle.
For your Laplacian $\Delta$ you get
$$\Delta \psi_\theta(n) = \psi_\theta(n) - \frac{(e^{-i\theta} + e^{i\theta})\psi_\theta(n)}{2} = (1 - \cos(\theta)) \psi_\theta(n)$$
So $\Delta$ has spectrum the interval $[0, 2]$ with the same generalized eigenvectors.

This is not intended as a rigorous proof.

Comment: Thank you. I know that the spectrum of $\Delta$ is $[0,2]$, but I wonder if there is some expression for the spectral family $(E_\lambda)_{\lambda \in \mathbb{R} }$ of $\Delta$.

Comment: There is something wrong with the right-hand "equality" in the last equation.

Comment: @Dan Asimov: thanks, I edited it.